# Removing an add-on/extension?

Tags: add-on, delete

I had Two-Mile redirect add-on/extension installed.

I have since removed it.

Now when Im trying to register a member, upon clicking the activation link, it stats

> Unable to load the following extension file:
>
> ext.twomile_login_redirect.php

Any idea on how I can remove it fully?

**UPDATE**

Can I simply (or safely) remove these two rows from the database?

[image: database]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that table is the only place extensions are registered (as long as the extension doesn't also include a "Module").

You can safely delete those rows. You could also just set `enabled` to `n` which will disable the extension.